# Apex:input date with only month and year

Tags: visualforce

I have a visual force page with an apex controller. In the controller I have a variable `Date date1`. In the page I have an `<apex:input type="date" value="{!date1}"/>`. Everything works fine.

Now I need to have only a month-year selector, no day has to be showed. One option could be to use instead two number input, or a picklist (for months) and a number (for the year) but I'd like to mantain a calendar standard element.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use jQuery to achieve that.

The following jsFiddle has a working example.
http://jsfiddle.net/bopperben/DBpJe/

This jsFiddle was created by a user on the following post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: The next question is, how is it going to be stored in Salesforce?

Comment: @Nick Cook. I agree. But since the OP mentioned that he is also considering creating 2 separate fields to capture month and year, I would assume the storage part is figured out already.